# Fatal Exception Main - startActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am totally new at Android / Java. I am trying to create an app that will connect to my TCP server to get data from mySQL.

I have the following: MainActivity - this is login screen. After entering the username and password, I connect to my server

```
->startService(new Intent(this, tcpConnectionService.class));
```

The server verifies the user+pwd, and send me back response.
I am analyzing the response and if it is OK, I want to open new activity - for some data request.

```
static public void LOGIN_RESPONSE (String data)
{
    Toast.makeText(mainContext, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //open search activity
    if (data.equals("LOGIN_OK"))
        mainContext.startActivity(new Intent(null, sn_search.class));
}
```

but unfortunately, I get the exception...

```
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  ... 11 more
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:621)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at kushnir.mkssql.MainActivity.LOGIN_RESPONSE(MainActivity.java:84)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at kushnir.mkssql.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
04-03 19:05:11.008: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  ... 14 more
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     ... 11 more
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2702)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at kushnir.mkssql.MainActivity.LOGIN_RESPONSE(MainActivity.java:82)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at kushnir.mkssql.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
04-03 19:38:53.818: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: This line, buried in the stack, seems to be the important one: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: What is `mainContext` and how was it set?

Comment: private static Context mainContext;

Comment: om OnCreate: mainContext = this.getApplicationContext();

Comment: Pretty new to Android myself, but ... I think you want to use the `Activity` as the context for calling `startActivity`, not the `getApplicationContext()`.  In the main `Activity`, either set `mainContext` or some other field to `this`, and use that when calling `startActivity`.  No guarantees that I know what I'm talking about, though.

Comment: YES!!! you are right - i changed the declaration to  mainContext = this; now it's cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this call:

```
mainContext.startActivity(new Intent(null, sn_search.class));
```

`mainContext` needs to be an `Activity`; setting it to `getApplicationContext()` makes it a different kind of `Context` instead of an `Activity`, which leads to the exception.  To resolve this, either set `mainContext` (or some other field) to `this` somewhere in the body of the `Activity` class.  If the `startActivity` call itself occurs inside the body of your `Activity` class (or a `Fragment` class), you don't need an object at all; this is good enough:

```
startActivity(new Intent(null, sn_search.class));
```

(but it's probably necessary to use an `Activity`, instead of `null`, as the first parameter of `new Intent`; there seem to be two exceptions being thrown from your app).

Comment: This Exception has nothing to do with getApplicationContext... The problem is with the null in the Intent's constructor.

Comment: @kupsef There are two exceptions in the stacktrace (lines 20 and 45 of the trace).  They could be from two different runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Intent(null, sn_search.class)
```

Why null? You should specify the context.

Look at your exception, it tells you where the problem is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
 at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2702)
```

The Intent's constructor raised a NullPointerException. Guess why:)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the intent before you start the Activity: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: While this might appear to work, it's quite unclear that this is an appropriate solution (on the contrary, it is probably not a fit for the UI flow likely desired here).  Please see the more detailed coverage in comments.